# How to convert RSA Public key to string and vice versa?

Tags: android, rsa

I want to achieve end to end encryption in my app and I want my Public key to be a string so that I can send it to server. Kindly tell me a way to convert public Key to string and vice versa.

Comment: People who downvote don't get notified of comments, so you're not going to find out from them. However this doesn't seem like a question that is on topic here, but it instead seems like you're asking someone to write the code for you. This is not a personal tutorial writing service, you should show a great deal of research and effort before asking a question. You can take the [tour], have a look at [ask] and see what's on topic at the [help/on-topic] for some more information.

Comment: @HenryTwist if you look closely at all stack overflow question all answer nearly provide some sort of code written by others. Also i am not asking simeone to write thousand lines of code for me at best i think my question wouldn't take more than 10 to 15 lines of code but its these lines i dont know about thats why i am asking here.

Comment: I would say I've looked at quite a few questions, and the good ones usually have a simple Q&A style and focus one one specific programming problem. Yours is very broad and unfocused. Do you want to know how to send network requests? How to implement networking in Android specifically? How to generate a public key? How to convert it to a string? You can take a look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) which explains this in more detail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your main question seems to be "a java code to convert public key to string and vice versa" and this can be done with a few lines of code.

The full example code generates a RSA key pair, get the encoded form of the public key (as byte array) and encodes this in
**Base64 encoding** to a string. The encoding is done with the Android util class. Then the string needs to be transported to the
server, decoded to a byte array and this byte array runs into a key factory that "regenerates" the public key - voila.

Kindly note that the code has **no exception handling** and is for educational purpose only.

output:

```
Convert RSA public key into a string an dvice versa
publicKey: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 18853651626448533042344052742185586831509096183921137436644620443732807152716528158465416708071104899767862289783079092216042499687784322092232163872332358586822678596223733228124113017356896219191227134298362353552882770945818159114272146532048929436504145362418430766823867890113522564795700689158702507402243560009550536419065620409534494384621580364502393563063483223294632627903706549112325066113361455750410642281763368591922729105346933211850575970566025026523917327761707615319008741255611490792106558703015066844972642677443110535667601315009551275389632601989979561472926080344790824117481932026867279062677
  public exponent: 65537
publicKeyString: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAlVmFPS+dIDcJILVZMM9hdQwEiLcHx7SVYF5gOrakPH7ZzilcOjWYcR47qktQAUu97JbLu3h3WPmm1nkgSXU1lVBoqc8pA1BHmzdvMK61A/F77nspDce0QqH5f5kQvYcuQrl+cCUvaTI/3/WBWwRIO2xGKMKRIgiBWDN/HVsqYU2O2pAJnLKQbz9NkkfGNVdzn4H21hi0shCVWCpt80zZkn0gm3oWtCGHOnyszXUOiw7inAdGkNGiZRyiFOUmFNRKLIYM3WiyU1NRGVrjto9NH/E53JdgSyBEu7kkWMLJqNuwj+DNQFu3Qq5VrNxwWggrwhFG+K0y0+Ed+scT003mlQIDAQAB
publicKeyServer: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  params: null
  modulus: 18853651626448533042344052742185586831509096183921137436644620443732807152716528158465416708071104899767862289783079092216042499687784322092232163872332358586822678596223733228124113017356896219191227134298362353552882770945818159114272146532048929436504145362418430766823867890113522564795700689158702507402243560009550536419065620409534494384621580364502393563063483223294632627903706549112325066113361455750410642281763368591922729105346933211850575970566025026523917327761707615319008741255611490792106558703015066844972642677443110535667601315009551275389632601989979561472926080344790824117481932026867279062677
  public exponent: 65537
```

code:

```
import android.util.Base64;

import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        System.out.println("Convert RSA public key into a string an dvice versa");
        // generate a RSA key pair
        KeyPairGenerator keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keygen.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair keyPair = keygen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        System.out.println("publicKey: " + publicKey);
        // get encoded form (byte array)
        byte[] publicKeyByte = publicKey.getEncoded();
        // Base64 encoded string
        String publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(publicKeyByte, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        System.out.println("publicKeyString: " + publicKeyString);
        // ... transport to server
        // Base64 decoding to byte array
        byte[] publicKeyByteServer = Base64.decode(publicKeyString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        // generate the publicKey
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKeyServer = (PublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyByteServer));
        System.out.println("publicKeyServer: " + publicKeyServer);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code helped I have also tried converting PrivateKey to string and to convert it back to PrivateKey I used 'privateKeyServer = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyByteServer));' but the keys are not the same. It would be great if you tell me about this too.

Comment: My own implementations get the same result, hm, I think you should ask another question as this is the Stackoverflow guideline.

Comment: I have asked question here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/q/66850656/14930941