# Converting string to PrivateKey does not give the same Keys in android

Tags: android, rsa

I am converting a PrivateKey to String and vice versa using the following functions:

```
  private static String privateKeyToString(PrivateKey privateKey)
    {
        byte[] privateKeyByte = privateKey.getEncoded();
        String privateKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(privateKeyByte, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return privateKeyString;
    }

    private static PrivateKey stringToPrivateKey(String privateKeyString)
    {
        byte[] privateKeyByteServer = Base64.decode(privateKeyString, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        // generate the publicKey
        KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
        try {
            keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PrivateKey privateKeyServer = null;
        try {
            privateKeyServer = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyByteServer));
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return privateKeyServer;

    } //To generate RSA Keys
 private static Map<String, Object> getRSAKeys() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        keys.put("private", privateKey);
        keys.put("public", publicKey);
        return keys;
    }
```

Now the key generated with `stringToPrivateKey()` is "OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey" while the original private key was "OpenSSLRSAPrivateCRTKey" and these are not the same keys. How to get same keys after conversions?

**Original key:**

```
OpenSSLRSAPrivateCrtKey{modulus=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,publicExponent=10001}
```

**Converted key**

```
OpenSSLRSAPrivateKey{modulus=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
```

Comment: I run your "toString" and "fromString" methods and the **encoded** private keys (my sample key and the reencoded one) are **equal**. Is it possible that you compare two different private key types (PrivateKey and RSAPrivateCrtKey) ? Where are your printouts for "Original key" and "Converted key" from ?

Comment: @MichaelFehr i am comparing orignalKey. toString() to recodedKey. toString(). Are you using Android Bade64 or java?

Comment: As originalKey and recodedKey are **objects** you cant't compare the string-encoded ones. Instead you can compare the encoded forms (e.g. originalKey.getEncoded()) with Arrays.equal.... I used Android Base64 but it will work with Java as well.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to get String

```
public String getPrivateKey(String option)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

    switch (option) {

        case "pkcs1-pem":
            String pkcs1pem = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
            pkcs1pem += Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            pkcs1pem += "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----";

            return pkcs1pem;

        case "pkcs8-pem":
            String pkcs8pem = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n";
            pkcs8pem += Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            pkcs8pem += "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

            return pkcs8pem;

        case "base64":
            return Base64.encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        default:
            return null;

    }

}
```

and use this method to get privateKey

```
public static PrivateKey stringToPrivate(String private_key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException,
        InvalidKeyException,
        IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException {

    try {
        // Read in the key into a String
        StringBuilder pkcs8Lines = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(private_key));
        String line;
        while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
            pkcs8Lines.append(line);
        }

        // Remove the "BEGIN" and "END" lines, as well as any whitespace

        String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

        // Base64 decode the result

        byte[] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.decode(pkcs8Pem, Base64.DEFAULT);

        // extract the private key

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        return privKey;

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;


}
```

Comment: in case "pkcs1-pem": and case "pkcs8-pem": you are encoding public keys.

Comment: I have tried you solution but the result is not the same. The keys are still different